# Entity framework dynamic table name part

Tags: c#, entity-framework

We have table name include year. Its look like "Item_2015" "Item_2014" is there any way work with ef ? I need generate Item class but it should work with year suffix for db. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a constructor on you context that receive the suffix as a parameter, and map the name of your tables using Fluent Api

```
public class Item
{
  //...
}

public class YourContext: DbContext 
{
    private string suffix="_2015";

    public SchoolDBContext(string _suffix): base() 
    {
       this.suffix=_suffix;
    }

    public DbSet<Item> Items{ get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
         // Map an Entity Type to a Specific Table in the Database
         modelBuilder.Entity<Item>().ToTable("Item"+suffix);

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Comment: would this not limit you to only being able to query from a single table - say you wanted access to 2013 -2015 the only way you could do that here is by creating multiple dbcontext instances which would be messy